# How do you add the POST method to this Twitter API request?

Tags: api, http, post, twitter

When I try to send a tweet using this URL: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?oauth_consumer_key=&oauth_timestamp=1614779803&oauth_nonce=29969093&oauth_version=1.0&status=First%20tweet%20with%20this%20app&oauth_token=&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature= I get the following response:

```
{"errors":[{"code":86,"message":"This method requires a POST."}]}
```

.
How do I add the *POST* method to this URL request?

Comment: Can you add more details on what you've tried - no way to figure out how to help without knowing the language and having some code. Please read the getting started docs on this site - you'll be glad you did because they explain the best way to get an answer.

Comment: I tried adding *method=POST* to the URL but it doesn’t seam to work.

Comment: always provide more details with your question, Kindly, follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What code are you using? What programming language?